# something like cron (timer) in gevent

Tags: python, timer, gevent

How can I make classical timer in gevent?

I'm currently using gevent.spawn_later but is there a way to use core.timer like saying "do callback on interval" just like cron does?

```
def callback():
    # do something
    print '!'

timer = core.timer(10, callback)
timer.start()

outpout:
0s
10s  !
20s  !
30s  !
```

Comment: Hmm, why is a greenlet looping endlessly, calling a callback and sleeping, not enough?

Comment: I use this in gunicorn so it is web server, and I don't know how to do that. I just have handler function, but I could probably insert that code before that. It looks kinda bad to do that because if I need 10 timers, I need 10 callbacks. Is that even gonna work with gunicorn?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

On the top of my head, you can use gevent.sleep in a loop:

```
import gevent
import gevent.monkey

gevent.monkey.patch_all()

INTERVAL = 10

def callback():
    # do something
    print "!"

def loop():
    while True:
        gevent.sleep(INTERVAL)
        callback()

gevent.Greenlet.spawn(loop)
```

Of course, you may put this code in a nice API such as core.timer. But I'll let all the fun for you :)

Comment: time drift from callback()

Answer (score 18):

It depends how accurately you want your job to be scheduled.  There are a couple of mechanisms:

[This blog](http://techualization.blogspot.co.uk/2011/08/simple-job-scheduling-with-gevent.html) has a neat trick for using `gevent.spawn_later` to create a timer:

```
def schedule(delay, func, *args, **kw_args):
    gevent.spawn_later(0, func, *args, **kw_args)
    gevent.spawn_later(delay, schedule, delay, func, *args, **kw_args)
```

Or of course you can simply sleep in a loop which is probably more readable:

```
def run_regularly(self, function, interval, *args, **kwargs):
    while True:
        gevent.sleep(interval)
        function(*args, **kwargs)
```

However both of these will drift over time, particularly if your function takes time to complete relative to the interval.  You can compensate by adjusting the sleep interval by the time the function takes to execute:

```
def run_regularly(self, function, interval, *args, **kwargs):
    while True:
        before = time.time()
        function(*args, **kwargs)

        duration = time.time() - before
        if duration < interval:
            gevent.sleep(interval-duration)
        else:
            warning("function %s duration exceeded %f interval (took %f)" % (
                function.__name__, interval, duration))
```

This will still drift, just not quite as much...

Comment: What is `self` for?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a version that initializes to the whole second and subsequently corrects for any drift. It can also be used to divide a period of time up into several sections for different purposes:

```
import time
import gevent

def print_time(sleep_time, tag):
    print time.time(), tag
    time.sleep(sleep_time)


def run_regularly(function, intervals, sleep_time=0.1, round_length=1):
    _, init  = divmod(time.time(), 1)
    gevent.sleep(1 - init)
    while True:
        before = time.time()
        _, offset = divmod(before, round_length)
        for div in intervals:
            function(sleep_time, div)
            after = time.time() - before
            if after < (div * round_length):
                gevent.sleep((div * round_length) - after - (offset / len(intervals)))

gevent.spawn(run_regularly, print_time, [0.2, 0.8, 1.0])

while 1:
    gevent.sleep(0.1)
```